# GradNorm implementation in Tensorflow 2.x / Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have been trying to implement Gradnorm from the paper, GradNorm: Gradient Normalization for Adaptive Loss Balancing in Deep Multitask Networks. I have been having some trouble figuring out how to do this since I have a two-head model and need to balance the gradients accordingly.
I am using Keras for this work and using the `model.fit()` function to train my model.

So far, I have tried to use a callback to implement this like:

```
class GradNorm(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def __init__(self, model, optimizer, alpha=0.2):
        super(GradNorm, self).__init__()
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.model = model
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.l_hat_1 = self.l_hat_2 = self.l_hat_avg = 1.0
        self.inv_rate_1 = self.inv_rate_2 = 1.0
        self.weights_shared = self.model.weights[:20] # all shared layer weights
        
        self.w1 = self.w2 = 1.0
        self.l01 = self.l02 = -1.0
        self.task_losses = []
    
  def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):

    loss_t1 = logs.get('loss1')
    loss_t2 = logs.get('loss2')
    self.task_losses.append((loss_t1, loss_t2))
    
    # Weight losses
    l1 = tf.multiply(loss_t1, self.w1)
    l2 = tf.multiply(loss_t2, self.w2)
    
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        
        G1R = tape.gradient(tf.constant(loss_t1, dtype=tf.float32), self.weights_shared)
        G2R = tape.gradient(tf.constant(loss_t2, dtype=tf.float32), self.weights_shared)
    
    G1 = tf.norm(G1R, ord=2)
    G2 = tf.norm(G2R, ord=2)
```

However, this fails even at this point because G1R returns an array of `None`

Would really appreciate any help on this
Thank You

Comment: You can't use a callback for this because the gradients have already been applied at that point. You will probably need to [overwrite train_step](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit) or write a custom `Optimizer` class.

Comment: Could you please explain further? I am not sure which would be simpler to implement because it does not seem trivial to me to write a custom optimizer.

Comment: Overwriting train step should be simpler. You can check the first example in the tutorial I linked in the other comment; that is basically the "default" train step which you can use as a basis. After the tape computes the gradients, you can modify them before applying the modified gradients with the optimizer. I'm afraid I can't say much more than that since I'm not familiar with the paper.

Comment: I see, thank you xdurch0, I will try that.
One more quick question if you are able to answer, when I compute the gradients wrt the model weights, and then inspect them, I see some fields (not all) as None. Does that mean that the gradients for those weights are none? If so, how can that be possible if I am able to regularly train the model using model.fit()